# Displaying error messages for FormItems in Flex

Tags: forms, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a bunch of checkboxes that I group under the mx:FormItem tag, which, let's say is called Application

```
<mx:FormItem  id ="application" label="Application" labelStyleName="labelStyle" width="520">
```

These need to be validated. Particularly, it needs to be checked if at least one of these checkboxes have been selected. And this is done when the user attempts to submit the button, so I have something to the effect of  :

```
<mx:Button width="60" label="Send" id="submit" click="doValidation();" />
```

The doValidation() function has a bunch of conditions that need to be checked, and upon passing these conditions , sets the errorMessage property for the Mx:FormItem tag, like this

```
private function doValidation():void
{
  if(check.condition) //  check.condition is  a stub
     Application.errorString= "You messed up"; 
}
```

However, this errorString is not displayed. I believe this is where I am stuck. Being relatively new to flex, i don't quite know my way around it yet. Can someone illustrate how this error message can be displayed. The internal logic is just fine, I have already debugged the code to see how it works, but

Comment: In this code, you are setting the errorString on"Application" whereas the FormItem is named "application".  Notice the case sensitivity difference.  That said, have you tried setting the errorString on the input instead of the formItem?

Comment: actually, that was just a typo here on my part. in the actual code, i am setting the errorString on application. Regardless, if I made a typing mistake, it would sprout open an error screaming possible use of undefined variable/object etc. So that isn't the problem. What do you imply by setting the errorString on the input ?

Comment: I don't imply anything. Usually I set the errorString on the input--I Guess in your case a CheckBox--and not on a FormItem.  But, I don't often use the form container, so I'm not completely sure.

Comment: yea, I am new to flex, apparently using a form container which IMO is the equivalent of a Form tag is not all that mandatory in this language. There are multiple checkboxes, setting the error string on either one is not going to adhere to the UI demands. Can't the error be rendered elsewhere on the page ?

Comment: I'd say the Flex Form Container is not the equivalent of an HTML Form tag.  A flex Form is just for layout; where as an HTML Form has no layout. A Flex form; has no built in ability to send data to a server; whereas an HTML Form is primarily used for sending data to the server.  Yes, you can create an error and display it anywhere on the page that you desire.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the heads up, how can I do that or where can I find the relevant source material ?

Comment: I don't think there is relevant source material to point you to, aside from generic tutorials on learning Flex.  I think the Flex in a Week Videos are still out there; and the Adobe Flex documentation includes lots of samples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to validate a check box directly but here is an example of a manually created validator for multiple check boxes found inside of a FormItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
    layout="vertical" 
    >

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function doValidation():void{
                var itemsSelected:int = 0;

                for each(var checkBox:CheckBox in app.getChildren()){
                    if(checkBox.selected){
                        itemsSelected++;
                    }
                }

                if(itemsSelected == 0){
                    app.filters = [errorGlow];
                    app.toolTip = "You must select at least one value";
                }else{
                    app.filters = [];
                    app.toolTip = "";
                }
            }

            private function checkBoxClicked(e:Event):void{
                if((e.currentTarget as CheckBox).selected == true){
                    app.filters = [];
                    app.toolTip = "";
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:GlowFilter id="errorGlow"
        color="0xFF0000" blurX="5" blurY="5"
        />

    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem id="app" 
            width="520"
            label="Application"
            >
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox1" label="Item 1" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox2" label="Item 2" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox3" label="Item 3" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox4" label="Item 4" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox5" label="Item 5" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox6" label="Item 6" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox7" label="Item 7" selected="false" click="checkBoxClicked(event)"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
    <mx:Button  width="60" label="Send" id="submit" click="doValidation()" />

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: By the way, you cannot use the id "application" directly in the main mx:Application tag since there is a variable inside this component named "application".